# Moise Problem set 1.3 ex 8

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Moise cites a the following theorem which holds in the algebra of the real numbers (please direct me to a proof of this as well):

If $ab-cd\ne0$ then the following system of equations:

${\begin{cases}ax+dy=e\\cx+by=f\end{cases}}$

is satisfied by exactly one pair of numbers $(x,y)$.

Does this theorem hold true in any commutative ring with unity? Does it hold true in any field?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely you mean $ab-cd\ne 0$? For a general commutative ring, the condition is that $ab-cd$ must be a unit in that ring.

Comment: Thanks. Can you direct to a proof of that condition (as well as the above theorem). Based on what your telling me I assume that it holds in any field because every element of a field (except 0) has an inverse.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm just beginning my journey in mathematics.